# How to prevent an accompanying C# project from showing up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am browsing a Visual Studio 2010 C# solution (not mine) that has the following hierarchy:

```
root solution folder\  
    solution.sln  
    project1 folder\  
        project1.proj  
    project2 folder\  
        project2.proj
```

If I ignore the `solution.sln` folder and double click directly on the `project1.proj` file, I can still see the other project (*project2*) in the Solution Explorer pane for the Visual Studio session that comes up!  The only way I can get rid of *project2* from appearing in *project1*'s Visual Studio session is by deleting the `solution.sln` file altogether.

What is it that makes a `.proj` file be aware of a solution file that exists elsewhere (in this case, one level above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a project file contains no reference to its "parent" solution file, it's obvious that this behavior is by design and has been for many versions.

Visual Studio scans the directory of the requested project file and, if necessary, the parent directory until it runs into and can open the associated solution file (i.e. a .sln file that contains a reference to the project file).

If a suitable .sln file cannot be found, it will be created in memory and you will be prompted to save the auto-created .sln file upon exit.

A way to verify this behavior, is to copy and paste a separate project folder  (from within a solution folder) to an unrelated location (e.g. your Desktop) and opening the project file. Visual Studio has automatically "wrapped" your project in a Solution, marked with a question mark and you'll be asked to save changes or not when exiting.

So from Visual Studio's perspective, there are no isolated projects. There are solutions that contain projects.

As a reference, here's [the MSDN page on Solutions and Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx)

Comment: Wim, thank you.  I have accepted your answer, and as you say, since the project file contains no reference to another solution file, there must be another explanation.  However, do you have any MSDN link that spells out this behavior? Also: In Visual Studio 2010, I do not see a question mark for the wrapper solution that is newly created by Visual Studio.

Comment: @Sabuncu I'm seeing the question mark in VS2013 but I'll take your word for it that it's not there in VS2010. It's nothing but eye candy anyway.

Comment: @Sabuncu The behavior is not spelled out per se, but implied by the contents of the .sln file (as stated in the MSDN link in my answer): the Solution file contains (among other things) the build configuration of the project(s) referenced within. Without a build configuration, your IDE would be little more than a glorified text editor because it wouldn't know what to do when you pressed F6...

Comment: And I will check the question mark on the 2013 installation I have elsewhere! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project file in Solution Explorer pane and select `New Solution Explorer View`. Then you can browse that one project only.

Comment: Although this is a solution to viewing a specific project without the rest of the solution it's contained in, it doesn't actually answer the question in the last sentence of the OP's post and so should be a comment. Sorry.

Comment: @WimOmbelets you also can unload the project 2 which is also in the right-click pop-up menu.

Comment: Snowell, in Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate), the option you mention is not displayed when I right click on the project folder.  FYI.